# SQLAlchemy: How to joint two group by

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to joint two group by SQLAchemy

```
done_1 = db.session.query(Tasks.user_1,func.count()).group_by(Tasks.user_1).all()
done_2 = db.session.query(Tasks.user_2,func.count()).group_by(Tasks.user_2).all()
all = done_1 + done_2
```

This is joint just two list not count by user

Comment: Can you explain better with an example of what is the data in the DB and what is the expected result you want  ?

Comment: Every row is task for two people and i want count how much task everyone have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to combine the results using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator and have just one sql query, executed, below should do the job (note dropped `.all()`) from both subqueries:

```
done_1 = (
    session.query(
        Tasks.user_1.label("user"),
        func.count().label("count"),
    )
    .group_by(Tasks.user_1)
)
# .all()

done_2 = (
    session.query(
        Tasks.user_2,
        func.count()
    )
    .group_by(Tasks.user_2)
)
# .all()

stmt = union_all(done_1, done_2).subquery()
stmt = select([stmt])

for row in stmt.execute():
    print(row)
```

Please also note usage of `.label(...)` to give name to returned columns (only needed on the first select) in case you would like to access results by name:

```
print(row.user, row.count)
```

---

Now, if it is possible that the same user value will appear both in `user_1` and `user_2` fields, these will be reported twice. However, if combining those into one row is desired, just perform another step before executing:

```
stmt = select([stmt.c.user, func.sum(stmt.c.count).label("count")]).group_by(stmt.c.user)
```

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: fixed by adding `.subquery` to the `union_all`.